# Delete elements from JList

Tags: java

I have a JList that I am populating from a MySQL database. This works fine and I can see the results in a JScrollPane, however, when I execute the query again the results are added to to JList; so if there are 10 rows of data, it shows 20 after 2 queries, a copy of each row.

I want to delete all elements in the JList before re-querying so that it only shows what is there, not duplicate data.

I have:

```
    ArrayList<String> results;
    JList list;
    JScrollPane listScroller;
    ... //button event and arraylist population

    for(int i=0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++){
        list.remove(i)
    }
    list = new JList(results.toArray);
    listScroller.setViewportView(list);
```

When I debug it, even thought there are 50 elements, i, in the for loop, stops at 25 and then throws an exception saying 25 is out of bounds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you removing every element or every second element?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to remove items if, right after, you assign a new `JList` object to `list` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve I am removing every element.

Comment: @ccheneson For some reason it just adds to the list when I create a new one, so I have all the elements plus some duplicate elements.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to iterate through elements that have been already removed. The turning point is exaxtly in the middle (at element 25th). Use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28765678/815227).

Comment: @NickSuwyn no you weren't ;) see answer. If you must iterate, remove from element `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is removing elements from the list (in each iteration the list's size is decremented by 1). So when you reach `i==25` the list's size is 25 and when you try to remove the 25th element you are out of bounds of the list.

Try this approach:

```
while (list.getModel().getSize() > 0) {
    list.remove(0);
}
```

**Edited by the OP:**
The problem with `list.remove(i)` in your loop is that every time an element in a JList is removed the index is filled in. So if `i = 0` and there are 10 elements, you remove the first and then there are only 9 elements and they take indexes 0 through 8. By the time you get to `i = 5` you only have 5 elements left and 4 is the top index so you get an out of bounds exception.

Avoid this by removing the first index (0) each time.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I will accept the answer as soon as I am permitted, five minutes haha! It seems that I was trying to remove (i) but when you remove an element from a JList they all change indexes always starting with 0. So while there were 50 initially, when i = 25 there where only 25 left meaning i = 25 was out of bounds. I just needed to always remove the first element. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a while loop :

```
DefaultListModel listModel = (DefaultListModel) yourJList.getModel();
listModel.removeAllElements();
```

Comment: This approach is only possible when you know the type of the model (you are risking to ClassCastException other way).

Answer (score 0):

Override data in the list will be faster....

```
list.setListData(new String[0])
```